# Schottky diode fails probably due to temperature - LED driver

Tags: power-supply, power, led-driver

I have designed a 3-channel LED driver using the [Diodes Inc ZXLD1371](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXLD1371.pdf). One channel supplies 6 RED LEDs in series, the other channel green LEDs and the other blue LEDs, all power LEDs. Due to the Vf differences, the Red LED channel Vout is lower (2.2V/LED total 13.2V) the others are 3.2V/LED, total output 19.2V. The source is 24VDC. The current is set to 4A per channel (many LEDs in parallel). The problem is with the RED channel - the schottky diode fails (burns) after a few hours working. But the diodes on the other channels keep working fine. I understand that the duty cycle is much lower on RED channel. The diodes used are [SS54](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/5335/SMASS540000S54.pdf) (40V 5A), should be fine.
I´m out of ideas.
Other SS54 datasheets: [Mfgr-2](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/80/20190806165140-2504996.pdf), [Mfgr-3](https://www.utmel.com/components/ss54-diode-schottky-5a-40v-sma-video-faq?id=1956#cat10), [Mfgr-4.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2110121330_YONGYUTAI-SS54_C2904822.pdf)

The driver is working in buck mode. The schematic for one of the channels is attached (they are all the same). I haven´t measured the temperature in the diode. I have used the Diodes´ calculation tool, and the inductor is a CDRH127R of 15uH. There are 6 LEDs in series in a string, with 6 strings in parallel. What blows my mind is that only the diode in the RED LEDs string fails. And this is the string with the lowest Vf, compared to the others. The other diodes should fail too, because they are subjected to the same current and conditions, but they don´t, at least not at the same time. It takes some hours for the fail to occur. The MOSFET is the NCE3035 (30V 35A). My question is: could the lower duty cycle be playing a role in this fail? Should I use a higher current rated diode?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKPTl.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello there -- please add schematic and layout details.

Comment: How hot does it get? What’s the leak voltage and current stress?

Comment: Unfortunately your question was closed due to lack of details. If you edit & improve the question it could be reopened. In the ZXLD1371 datasheet there are different design configurations, a schematic of your design would be very helpful. Other issues such as the number of LEDs (strings), MOSFET and Inductor type, are unknown. I suspect you may be running the Schottky diode near or over it's limits. Review the current derating curve in the SS54 datasheet then consider the operating point of your circuit. Depending on the diode's exact brand and body style some of the specifications may vary.

Comment: Thiago Rodrigues - Can you please link to the datasheets of that specific inductor, specific MOSFET and your specific SS54 diode (a site member has kindly linked several, but as you are improving the question, please link *all* of the relevant, correct, datasheets including the one for your specific diode). Also can you link the PCB layout from your EDA software, just in case anything looks problematic. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware, there are no values or part numbers on the schematic, so people will have to make assumptions about what values have been used where.

Answer (score 1):

If the LED Vf is lower, the MOSFET duty cycle will be lower also, and the diode will conduct for longer during each cycle.

If current stays the same, diode dissipation is directly proportional to the fraction of the time it is conducting, the opposite of the MOSFET duty cycle.

Therefore, the diode for the red LEDs burns.

Note the datasheets disagree:

> 60°C/W, P.C.B. mounted with 2.0" X 2.0" (5 X 5 cm) copper pad areas.

> 60°C/W, P.C.B. mounted with 0.2" X 0.2" (5 X 5 mm) copper pad areas.

I think at least one of them is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you simulate this circuit with parasitics or at least find the max current though the zener.

Odds are the diode died a thermal death, by looking at the picture.  It also looks like there isn't a cap in partalel with the fet like in the reference diagram, put the capacitor in series with the fet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about capacitor, could you be more specific?

Comment: Look at the datasheet

Comment: I checked the datasheet first, but didn't see anything apparent.

Comment: There is a cap in parallel with the fet, is likely that this is causing the problem with over voltage and over current

Answer (score 0):

The long time to failure, among other factors, suggests a thermal failure.

The diode is very small (SMA package), and doesn't appear to have any special thermal consideration (large pours, vias, heatsinking).  The red LEDs have a lower voltage drop, putting a higher duty cycle on the diode.  At 5A and 0.55V, the diode dissipates 2.7W while on, and say at a 43% duty cycle and 4A, say 0.93W average.

Typical SMA thermal resistance with ~minimal pads might be 95 °C/W.  0.93W is 88°C rise, above an ambient which might be 25°C, putting the diode well over limit; it's already leaking ~1mA at 100°C, adding 24mW.  If it's more like 113°C, maybe it's more like 3mA, but also everything else around it gets hot, making it get hotter still, and... pretty soon it gets pushed over the point of no return, and magic smoke ensues.

Well, in this case "pretty soon" seems not to be the case, but that goes to show how marginal it was, and perhaps it would take mere minutes if it were just a few degrees warmer on the bench, or there was less air circulation.

Regarding the circuit, the filter capacitor C13 (at least I assume that's what it is, nothing is labeled as to value or purpose here), seems to be in the wrong place.  The datasheet shows diagrams for both buck and boost, which return the output filter capacitor to GND, not to ISENSE.  The load as well.  It's not clear if this has relevance to the immediate problem, but it may affect control dynamics/stability or efficiency.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I guess I can consider this case closed.

Comment: This circuit was designed for 2A per channel inititally, I decided to push it a little further, but it won´t be possible without replacing the diode. That means a new board, new stencil... anyways, I´ll  see what I can do. For the time being, I´ll set the current to 2.5A, maybe 3A max and test it. The capacitor C13 is there to reduce the ripple on the LEDs. as suggested by Diodes in their calculator tool (schematic attached). Thanks again for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Diodes Calculator tool schematic]
This is the schematic from the calculator tool, in which my design was based on.